# Using SoapUI Pro groovy script to generate multiple variable values

Tags: soapui, groovyshell

I am using SoapUI Pro to test some web services. I want to use a groovy script to generate yesterdays date and tomorrows date.

I want to know if its possible to use the same groovy script to generate both values or if a different groovy script is needed to generate each variable.

I have the following in my groovy script .

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today.previous()
def tomorrow = today.next()

def yesterdayDate = yesterday.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
def tomorrowDate = tomorrow.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

I'm not sure how to reference this within my web service request.

Using the below just inputs the last value that was generated by the script i.e. tomorrowDate

```
validFrom>${Dates#result}</validFrom>
```

I thought it might be possible to do something like ..

```
<validFrom>${Dates#result#tomorrowDate}</validFrom>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the dates to a property at test case or test suite level and in your xml just call those values.

```
//to set test suite level property
testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().setPropertyValue('yesterdayDate',yesterdayDate)
testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().setPropertyValue('tomorrowDate',tomorrowDate)
```

//Note: the property should exists otherwise you'll get an error.

```
//In the xml
<validFrom>${#TestSuite#yesterdayDate}</validFrom>
<validFrom>${#TestSuite#tomorrowDate}</validFrom>
```

You could do the same using properties at the test case level.

As a syntax correction it has been pointed out that

```
testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite()
```

should be written as

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite
```

and as i said in the suggested edit, both the approaches are correct and there are multiple ways to do something. I just provided one of the ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: Abhishek, you are right in your explanation, but "testRunner.testCase.testSuite" style is more groovy, isnt' it? IMHO Anyway, you've provided right and good answer.